# Foto no sale cuando uso explorer o microsoft edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, chrome

Una de mis fotos no sale cuando abro mi página web en explorer o en microsoft edge, pero si carga cuando abro mi página en chrome, firefox, y safari. Este es el código:

```
<img src="../Recursos/logoam.jpg" width="600" height="130" style="float:left">
```

Me carga en otra computadora cuando lo abro en explorer, por lo que no tengo idea de por qué pasa esto. La imagen es JPG, y las otras imágenes de mi página, que también están en la carpeta de Recursos si funcionan.

Comment: Debera añadir el codigo para saber mas sobre tu problema, como el archivo css, html y js

Comment: el código no se ve.

Answer (score 3):

A mi me pasaba eso es algo muy ¨tonto¨, revisa por favor que el nombre de

`Recursos/logoam.jpg`

en

`<img src="../Recursos/logoam.jpg" width="600" height="130" style="float:left">`

coincida *mayúsculas* y *minúsculas* con el nombre de la carpeta y del archivo.

IE es muy quisquilloso con ese detalle, una vez tuve ese problema y era porque los nombres de carpeta o de archivo no eran exactamente iguales; que no coincidían mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Answer (score 1):

En internet explorer es muy común estos errores, examina si internet explorer te ha bloqueado al cargar la imagen (Mediante el modo seguro)

En la parte inferior aparece "Modo seguro", desactivalo, ensaya de nuevo y mira mediante la consola si la ruta de la imagen allá cargado correctamente.

Añade alguna imagen para ayudarte mejor, saludos